# Rails, How to pre-generate ActiveStorage.Blob.preview

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am in Rails 6.1 (I assume there are no major changes in Rails 7)

I have a lot of videos in my system, and I am showing *previews* of them in the *index* view.

I use this:

```
<%= image_tag play_session.video.preview(resize_to_limit: [640, 360]) %>
```

And it works well. But the first time it is called it takes a lot of time:

```
Disk Storage (13737.8ms) Downloaded file from key: toyqvx3f980aqhh2l9uyno2cqp9e
```

And if I have several videos the time can be minutes.

It is worth saying that the second time the *index* is called. All the previews are there already. ActiveStorage makes some black magic that when a *preview* is generated it is persisted for future use.

I would like to *pregenerate* the *previews* so they are ready when the *index* is called.

Is this possible? or there is another pattern I should be using?

Comment: does your CDN provider have any caching functions?

Comment: Also take a look at memcached https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Comment: @jamesc I have updated the body so there is no confusion with the use of the _cache_ term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails [recommend to avoid](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-1-stable/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/blob/representable.rb#L53C55-L53C77) processing previews synchronously in views

You can add some asynchronous scheduled job (for example with Sidekiq) and invoke such code (of course you can add needed conditions)

```rb
PlaySession.find_each do |play_session|
  play_session.video.preview(resize_to_limit: [640, 360]).processed
end
```

[Processing](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-1-stable/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/preview.rb#L46-L49) a preview generates an image from its blob and attaches the preview image to the blob. Because the preview image is stored with the blob, it is only generated once

This way you will pregenerate previews

Comment: The [ActiveStorage::Preview.processed()](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Preview.html#method-i-processed) method is what I was missing, thanks!